# Replacing umlauts in JS

Tags: javascript, encoding, replace

I am comparing strings and have to replace umlauts in JS, but it seems JS does not recognize the umlauts in the strings. The text comes from the database and in the browser the umlauts do show fine.

```
function replaceUmlauts(string)
{
    value = string.toLowerCase();
    value = value.replace(/ä/g, 'ae');
    value = value.replace(/ö/g, 'oe');
    value = value.replace(/ü/g, 'ue');
    return value;
}
```

As search patterns I tried:

- "ä", "ö", "ü"
- /ä/, /ö/, /ü/
- "`&auml;`", "`&ouml;`", "`&uuml;`" (well total despair ;-))

To be sure, that it is not a matter with the replace function I tried indexOf:

```
console.log(value.indexOf('ä'));
```

But the output with all patterns is: `-1`

So I guess it is some kind of a problem with encoding, but as I said on the page the umlauts do just look fine.

Any ideas? This seems so simple...

EDIT:
Even if I found my answer, the problem was not really solved "at the root" (the encoding).
This is my page encoding:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

The database has: utf8_general_ci

Seems totally alright to me.

Comment: What encoding do you use in your database and what encoding do you use in your web page?

Comment: And what is the string??? Log it. Your approaches would work, but as you can see from your indexOf, your string does not contain an "ä".

Comment: `"bäg".replace(/ä/g, "ae"); // ==> "baeg"`, so something is probably off with your encoding

Comment: @Bergi: I logged the string and the ä is shown in the console, beofre and after teh replacing - it definitely is there :-) I wrote my encoding into the question, which seems totally okay with me, thats the reasion I chose the answer of Oleg. Many thanks to all to you - and yeah this way the problem is not really solved at "it's root"

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Either ensure that your script's encoding is correctly specified (in `<script>` tag or in page's header/meta if it's embedded) or specify symbols with `\uNNNN` syntax that will always unambiguously resolve to some specific Unicode codepoint.

For example:

```
str.replace(/\u00e4/g, "ae")
```

Will always replace ä with ae, no matter what encoding is set for your page/script, even if it is incorrect.

Here are the codes needed for Germanic languages:

```
// Ü, ü     \u00dc, \u00fc
// Ä, ä     \u00c4, \u00e4
// Ö, ö     \u00d6, \u00f6
// ß        \u00df
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works :-) I have utf-8 encoding on the page: <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> which seems totally right to me, so i will just work with that...

Comment: Here are more of the codes:                                                                              
// Ü, ü   \u00dc, \u00fc                                                                              
// Ä, ä   \u00c4, \u00e4                                                                              
// Ö, ö   \u00d6, \u00f6                                                                              
// ß   \u00df

Comment: Å for the Nordic countries: // Å,å: \u00c5, \u00e5

Answer (score 27):

If you are looking to replace the German Umlaute with cleverly respecting the case, use this (opensource, happy to share, all by me):

```js
const umlautMap = {
  '\u00dc': 'UE',
  '\u00c4': 'AE',
  '\u00d6': 'OE',
  '\u00fc': 'ue',
  '\u00e4': 'ae',
  '\u00f6': 'oe',
  '\u00df': 'ss',
}

function replaceUmlaute(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/[\u00dc|\u00c4|\u00d6][a-z]/g, (a) => {
      const big = umlautMap[a.slice(0, 1)];
      return big.charAt(0) + big.charAt(1).toLowerCase() + a.slice(1);
    })
    .replace(new RegExp('['+Object.keys(umlautMap).join('|')+']',"g"),
      (a) => umlautMap[a]
    );
}

const test = ['Übung', 'ÜBUNG', 'üben', 'einüben', 'EINÜBEN', 'Öde ätzende scheiß Übung']
test.forEach((str) => console.log(str + " -> " + replaceUmlaute(str)))
```

It will:

- Übung -> Uebung
- ÜBUNG -> UEBUNG
- üben -> ueben
- einüben -> einueben
- EINÜBEN -> EINUEBEN
- and the same for Ä, Ö
- and simple ß -> ss

Comment: Take note that this doesn't cover the (highly unusual) uppercase variant of the letter "ß" ("ẞ"). See https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F for details.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a function that replaces most common chars to produce a Google friendly SEO url:

```
function deUmlaut(value){
  value = value.toLowerCase();
  value = value.replace(/ä/g, 'ae');
  value = value.replace(/ö/g, 'oe');
  value = value.replace(/ü/g, 'ue');
  value = value.replace(/ß/g, 'ss');
  value = value.replace(/ /g, '-');
  value = value.replace(/\./g, '');
  value = value.replace(/,/g, '');
  value = value.replace(/\(/g, '');
  value = value.replace(/\)/g, '');
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but maybe not fast enough. I ended up using this: https://gist.github.com/yeah/1283961

Answer (score 4):

If you need a little snippet to convert german umlauts to html special charactes, here you go:

```html
function fixUmlauts(value) {
    value = value.replace(/ä/g, '&auml;');
    value = value.replace(/ö/g, '&ouml;');
    value = value.replace(/ü/g, '&uuml;');
    value = value.replace(/ß/g, '&szlig;');
    value = value.replace(/Ä/g, '&Auml;');
    value = value.replace(/Ö/g, '&Ouml;');
    value = value.replace(/Ü/g, '&Uuml;');
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first figure out what the character codes are that you're trying to replace. For example, depending on the character encoding, the characters could be in 8859, UTF-8 or something else. They could also be character symbols such as "ä"

Rather than guessing, print them out.

And beware that your incoming data may not use the same character set/character encoding consistently--you need to check on where the data is coming from.

So look at the incoming data by using string. [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

Check the character code before the `toLowerCase` to ensure that it is not changing things on you. You'll need to debug step by step.

Finally, check the character set settings in your editor to ensure that your typed ä is what it should be. You may want to specify it via the UTF8 value rather than typing ä, ö etc

Comment: No matter what you use as encoding in page, in JS everything is Unicode and a-umlaut will **always** have exactly same code.

Comment: I think my document encoding (my file in the editor) does not matter, because the text is coming from a database, so only the encoding in the database and in the html meta tags should be important or not? And your formatting of the function is rather confusing, it should be string.charCodeAt(0); (0 is the first position), but I really did not think of it and it was a good clue, unfortunately it did not help - the right unicode was returned before the toLowerCase as well as afterwards.