# Cant set Content-Disposition on Firebase function reponse

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that sends a `.xlsx` file like this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=" + file.metadata.metadata.displayName,
    'Content-Type': 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'Content-Length': buffer.length,
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'
});
res.end(buffer);
```

However, the `Content-Disposition` header does not seem to work. If I check the Chrome DevTools network tab and see the details of the request there is no `Content-Disposition` header (`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is present though).

Is this a limitation of Firebase functions? Or am I doing something wrong?

Also, it works if I host the functions locally (using `firebase serve --only functions`).

Thanks!

Comment: I have a questions, have you tried to print the "file.metadata.metadata.displayName" before send into the header?

Comment: Yes, I thought of it too, it has the expected value. I also tried printing all headers to the console and they all have the expected values.

Comment: Weird thing is that another function I created just for testing, that just sends the same headers as my function in the question, works. All headers are sent, including content-disposition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. It seems that Content-Disposition cannot contain special characters as per [RFC 2183 Section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2.3)

> Current [RFC 2045] grammar restricts parameter values (and hence
> Content-Disposition filenames) to US-ASCII.

Some browsers don't care about it and will work fine if there are special characters in the header parameters, but since the requests and responses go through Firebase they probably do some sort of filtering and don't allow special characters in the header parameters.

Comment: ty for sharing <3 Had a dynamic filename, didn't even realize that my example I investigated had german umlauts in it (äöü). (One solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54346022/1410503)